# How to check on WolframAlpha whether a differential form is exact or closed?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

I have $\omega(x, y) = \frac{2xy}{(1+x^2)^2} dx - \frac{1}{1+x^2}dy $. I'd like to check my results, but I don't know how to input the exercise.

I need to check if the differential form is exact, and to compute its potential.

Comment: You may wish to check out [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It's just as easy to check the mixed partials and then apply the standard procedure.